# How can I insert data from a CSV file into a dataframe using pandas.read_csv?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file like:

```
"B/G/213","B/C/208","WW_cis",,
"B/U/215","B/A/206","WW_cis",,
"B/C/214","B/G/207","WW_cis",,
"B/G/217","B/C/204","WW_cis",,
"B/A/216","B/U/205","WW_cis",,
"B/C/219","B/G/202","WW_cis",,
"B/U/218","B/A/203","WW_cis",,
"B/G/201","B/C/220","WW_cis",,
"B/A/203","B/U/218","WW_cis",,
```

and I want to read it into something like an array or dataframe, so that I would be able to compare elements from one column to selected elements from another columns. At first, I have read it straight into an array using `numpy.genfromtxt`, but I got stings like `'"B/A/203"'` with extra quotes `"` everywhere. I read somewhere, that pandas allows to strip strings of extra `"` so I tried:

```
class StructureReader(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename=filename
    def read(self):
        self.data=pd.read_csv(StringIO(str("RNA/"+self.filename)), header=None, sep = ",")
        self.data
```

but I get something like so:

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>               0
0  RNA/4v6p.csv`

How can I get my CSV file into some kind of a data type that would allow me to search through columns and rows?

Comment: [No such thing as a stupid question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_such_thing_as_a_stupid_question). couldn't resist, lol.

Comment: My comment now seems mean... the original question had that in the narrative.  I meant it to encourage the OP's quest for knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've mixed up StringIO with the file name. You either have your data as a string and then you use StringIO or you simply specify a file name (**not** using StringIO):

```
In [189]: data="""\
   .....: "B/G/213","B/C/208","WW_cis",,
   .....: "B/U/215","B/A/206","WW_cis",,
   .....: "B/C/214","B/G/207","WW_cis",,
   .....: "B/G/217","B/C/204","WW_cis",,
   .....: "B/A/216","B/U/205","WW_cis",,
   .....: "B/C/219","B/G/202","WW_cis",,
   .....: "B/U/218","B/A/203","WW_cis",,
   .....: "B/G/201","B/C/220","WW_cis",,
   .....: "B/A/203","B/U/218","WW_cis",,
   .....: """

In [190]:

In [190]: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=',', header=None, usecols=[0,1,2])

In [191]: df
Out[191]:
         0        1       2
0  B/G/213  B/C/208  WW_cis
1  B/U/215  B/A/206  WW_cis
2  B/C/214  B/G/207  WW_cis
3  B/G/217  B/C/204  WW_cis
4  B/A/216  B/U/205  WW_cis
5  B/C/219  B/G/202  WW_cis
6  B/U/218  B/A/203  WW_cis
7  B/G/201  B/C/220  WW_cis
8  B/A/203  B/U/218  WW_cis
```

PS you can decide what columns do you want to parse (to have in your data frame) - look at the `usecols` parameter

Or using file name

```
import os

df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('RNA', self.filename), sep=',', header=None, usecols=[0,1,2])
```

Answer (score 3):

### Data Insert

You are putting the string of the filename into your `DataFrame`, i.e. `RNA/4v6p.csv` is your data in location `row 0, col 0`.  You need to read in the file and store the data.  This can be done by removing `StringIO(str(...))` in your class

```
class StructureReader(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
    def read(self):
        self.data = pd.read_csv("RNA/"+self.filename), header=None, sep = ",")
        self.data
```

#### Code structure critique

I would also recommend removing the parent directory from being *hardcoded* by

1. Always passing in a full file path

   ```
   class StructureReader(object):
       def __init__(self, filepath):
           self.filepath = filepath
       def read(self):
           self.data = pd.read_csv(self.filepath), header=None, sep = ",")
           self.data
   ```
2. Making the directory an `__init__()` argument

   ```
   class StructureReader(object):
       def __init__(self, directory, filename):
           self.directory = directory
           self.filename = filename
       def read(self):
           self.data=pd.read_csv(self.directory+"/"+self.filename), header=None, sep = ",")
           # or import os and self.data=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(self.directory, self.filename)), header=None, sep = ",")
           self.data
   ```
3. Making the directory a constant attribute

   ```
   class StructureReader(object):
       def __init__(self, filename):
           self.directory = "RNA"
           self.filename = filename
       def read(self):
           self.data = pd.read_csv(self.directory+"/"+self.filename), header=None, sep = ",")
           # or import os and self.data=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(self.directory, self.filename)), header=None, sep = ",")
           self.data
   ```

This has nothing to do with reading your data, just a best practice commentary on structuring you code (Just my [$0.02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_two_cents)).

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can just read it with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', header=None)
```

that for me returns:

```
         0        1       2   3   4
0  B/G/213  B/C/208  WW_cis NaN NaN
1  B/U/215  B/A/206  WW_cis NaN NaN
2  B/C/214  B/G/207  WW_cis NaN NaN
3  B/G/217  B/C/204  WW_cis NaN NaN
4  B/A/216  B/U/205  WW_cis NaN NaN
5  B/C/219  B/G/202  WW_cis NaN NaN
6  B/U/218  B/A/203  WW_cis NaN NaN
7  B/G/201  B/C/220  WW_cis NaN NaN
8  B/A/203  B/U/218  WW_cis NaN NaN
```

you can then select only the columns you want with:

```
df = df[[0,1,2]]
```

and operate as usual with dataframes.